# Is stress linked to ulcers? What causes ulcers -- let alone bleeding ulcers?

Tags: stress, medical-myths, ulcers, subconscious-stress

People are always telling me to stop stressing so much otherwise I'll develop ulcers, and it seems to me, that for a long time stress was often associated with the development of ulcers. But I believe that it is much more complicated than that and why stress may be a contributing factor (as it seems for everything else), that it is hardly the culprit for an ulcer.

What causes ulcers? To what extent is it linked to stress?

And what are bleeding ulcers anyhow?

Comment: Lots of causes for ulcers, and stress is one but helicobacter infection might be the most common.